# openURL method works with a string, but not with a variable holding the same string

Tags: ios, objective-c

Edit: I figured out what was wrong, but can't post an answer yet since I am a new user. I will post my solution once I can.

I am using this code to open a link in the iPhone's web browser:

```
NSString *url;
NSLog(@"%d", [sender tag]);
if([sender tag] == 0) 
    url = [approvedDict objectForKey:@"ig"];
else if([sender tag] == 1) 
    url = [approvedDict objectForKey:@"yt"];
else if([sender tag] == 2) 
    url = [approvedDict objectForKey:@"tw"];
else if([sender tag] == 3) 
    url = [approvedDict objectForKey:@"pt"];
else if([sender tag] == 4) 
    url = [approvedDict objectForKey:@"fb"];
NSLog(@"%@", url);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

When using this code (which is the target action of a button press), nothing happens. However, if I take the EXACT string given by **NSLog(@"%@", url)** and put it where "url" is in the last line it works. I'm stumped as to what is going on; anyone have any clue? Thanks.

Comment: Is that the case for all values of `url` (from your `approvedDict`)?

Comment: Yes - Those keys are all references to strings that are links.

Comment: How can we help without knowing what the `url` string contains?

Comment: There are so many different urls that it can contain - Let's just say for example "http://www.google.com". When I put @"http://www.google.com" where url is on the last line, it works fine. However, if this url is contained within the url variable, and I keep the current code, it does not work. I know this is the current value of url by the NSLog method.

Comment: `@"google.com"` is *not* a URL. It's a string that looks like a domain name. A valid URL would be `@"http://google.com"`.

Comment: If you really do have `@"http://google.com"` (perhaps the http was lost in the comment), then make sure there is no extra whitespace in the string. Perhaps a newline at the end or something similar.

Comment: My bad - stack overflow took http out and turned it into a hyperlink. I tried checking for and removing whitespace, but unfortunately that was not it either. Lord Zsolt's answer gets me to the web browser, but it cannot connect to the website.

Comment: Your description is too vague. Post an actual block of code, with a specific URL in a variable that fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

If the url has any special characters, you need to percent escape them.

Instead of just opening the url like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

add

```
NSString *encodedString = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *urlToOpen = [NSURL URLWithString: encodedString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlToOpen];
```

Comment: The web browser opens now, but Safari can never connect to the server. Might there be another step?

Comment: I don't know whether you can get a response that the Safari failed to open a link or not. Are you sure if you open the same URL by hand (ex: Safari on your Mac), it works?